# Backup individual Raven database

Tags: ravendb

In an old version of Raven (r888) I had an individual database backed up with the following command

```
"C:\RavenDB\Server\Raven.Backup.exe" --url=http://localhost:8089/databases/Production --dest=C:\temp\raven\production
```

This would place the backup of the Production database into the destination directory.

On the latest unstable version, after upgrading, the command no longer executes and an error is returned

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

The [docs](http://ravendb.net/docs/server/administration/backup-restore?version=2) mention being able to backup the entire server but there is no mention of how to isolate this to a single database?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that your path to the executable is wrong? (Replace Server with Backup)
"C:\RavenDB\Backup\Raven.Backup.exe"

Answer (score 0):

Actually, we always backup a single db.
To execute on a single db, you use  the url `http://localhost:8089/databases/Production` note the /databases/Production there.

Comment: It looks like the Raven.Backup.exe is no longer in my server folder. So that is the true problem here. I also can't find it in any of my nuget packages?

Where does Raven.Backup.exe live now?